# How to select columns in R data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
a
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

I want to select `X1,X8,X9`
So I write it like this

```
colNum <- dim(a)[2]
ata1<-a[,c(1,8:colNum-1)]
```

However,the result is

```
data1
X1 X7 X8 X9
1  1  7  8  9
2  0  0  0  0
```

Cannot figure out why `X7` appears?

Comment: Why not just do `a[,c("X1", "X8", "X9)]` ?

Comment: You have a problem of operations precedence, put `colNum-1` into parenthesis, i.e. `a[, c(1, 8:(colNum - 1))]`

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I guess OP wants to hard code it so it will work with indices instead of certain names.

Comment: Because of operator precedence (see `?Syntax`; `:` has a higher precedence than `-`) and because many operations in R are vectorized (try e.g. `4:6-1`).